# slideshow:false is not working in flexslider

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to stop slidershow in button click and revert back in close button click.I tried to refer flexslier with block id and slider class.now flex slider is still auto sliding after the button click

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   $(".playButton").on('click',function(){
     $('#customerspeak .flexslider').flexslider({
         slideshow: false
      });
      $(".close_icon").on('click',function(){
     $('#customerspeak .flexslider').flexslider({
         slideshow: true
      });
  });
```

```html
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/css/flexslider.css" />  
<div id="customerspeak">
<div class="view view-customerspeak view-id-customerspeak view-display-id-block view-dom-id-fd7f21856725b4636fc94050afae3128">
        
  
  
      <div class="view-content">
      <div id="flexslider-1" class="flexslider flexslider-processed">
  <ul class="slides"><li class="flex-active-slide" data-thumb-alt="" style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%; position: relative; opacity: 1; display: block; z-index: 2;">
    <div class="contentContainer">
   <section class="panelSec">
   <div class="video-contain">
      <div class="cus_heading">
     <span class="field-content"><a href="">customer speak</a></span>   </div>
      <div class="content__desc">
     <div class="field-content"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nibh praesent nisl sodales nostra, eros vestibulum, duis lorem lobortis arcu quis in amet. Lorem orci augue proin in sodales</p>
</div>   </div>
   <div class="playVideo playButton"><div class="field-content">play</div></div>
    <div class="content__teaser col-md-12">
  
 <div class="customerName col-md-12">
    <div class="field-content"></div>   
 </div>
   </div>
  
</div>   
  </section>
   </div>
    <div class="close_icon" style="display: block;"><div class="field-content temp">close</div>
    
 <style>
 

  </style>
<script>

</script>

</li>
<li data-thumb-alt="" style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%; position: relative; opacity: 0; display: block; z-index: 1;" class="">
  
   <div class="contentContainer">
   <section class="panelSec">
   <div class="video-contain">
      <div class="cus_heading">
     <span class="field-content"><a href="">customer speak content</a></span>   </div>
      <div class="content__desc">
     <div class="field-content"><p>sample&nbsp;customer speak content description sample&nbsp;customer speak content description&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
</div>   </div>
   <div class="playVideo playButton"><div class="field-content">play</div></div>
    <div class="content__teaser col-md-12">
   
 <div class="customerName col-md-12">
    <div class="field-content">PINK</div>   
 </div>
   </div>
  
</div>   
  </section>
   </div>
    <div class="close_icon" style="display: block;"><div class="field-content temp">close</div></div>
    
 <style>
 

  </style>
<script>

</script>

</li>
<li data-thumb-alt="" style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%; position: relative; opacity: 0; display: block; z-index: 1;" class="">
 
   <div class="contentContainer">
   <section class="panelSec">
   <div class="video-contain">
      <div class="cus_heading">
     <span class="field-content"><a href="">Customer Speak</a></span>   </div>
      <div class="content__desc">
     <div class="field-content"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nibh p, eros vestibulum, duis lorem lobortis arcu quis in amet. Lorem orci augue proin in sodales</p>
</div>   </div>
   <div class="playVideo playButton"><div class="field-content">play</div></div>
    <div class="content__teaser col-md-12">
   
 <div class="customerName col-md-12">
    <div class="field-content">Customer Speak</div>   
 </div>
   </div>
  
</div>   
  </section>
   </div>
    <div class="close_icon" style="display: block;"><div class="field-content temp">close</div></div>
    
 <style>
 

  </style>
<script>

</script>

</li>
</ul><ol class="flex-control-nav flex-control-paging"><li><a href="#" class="flex-active">1</a></li><li><a href="#" class="">2</a></li><li><a href="#" class="">3</a></li></ol><ul class="flex-direction-nav"><li class="flex-nav-prev"><a class="flex-prev" href="#" style="z-index: 1;">Previous</a></li><li class="flex-nav-next"><a class="flex-next" href="#" style="z-index: 1;">Next</a></li></ul></div>
    </div>
  
  
  
  
  
  
</div></div>
```

Comment: So you sure the playButton should stop and the close button should start?

Comment: yes  same as you tell

Comment: Please set up a working example and clean up your code. Your HTML is a BIG mess and no fun to look into it.